# Can I make this tripod I found in the trash work for my camera?

Tags: tripod

I have a run-of-the-mill digital camera with a 1/4-20 UNC tripod connector.

I found a tripod in the trash and would like to connect my camera to it.

However, it's either missing a bit, or a completely different system.

Is there an adapter I could purchase, or some other way to make this tripod fit?

[image: top part of the found device showing a extension arm with some kind of thumbscrew]

Answer (score 10):

That is not a camera tripod. It looks more like a light stand, music stand, or microphone stand with a part missing.

It may be stable enough for a small camera but you would have to jury-rig something to make it work for you.

I would start by removing the upper part to see if it has a 1/4" or 3/8" stud that could be used to mount a camera tripod head.

[image]

Comment: In any case, unless your space is limited, keep it, it is useful to mount flashes, microphones, backgrounds, reflectors....